# send data from one screen to another screen flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am trying to pass data from one screen to another screen.

```
List<SubCategoryData>categoryNames = new List<SubCategoryData>();
  List<String>categorieslist = [];
  bool isFirst=true;

  Future<SubCategoryModel>fetchCategories(BuildContext context) async {

    String url = "http://106.51.64.251:380/onnet_api/subcatListByCategory.php";

    var body = new Map<String,String>();
    body['publisherid']= 102.toString();
    body['tag'] = "category";
    body['subtag']= "list";
    body['parentId'] = 10.toString();

    http.Response res = await http.post(url,body: body);
    final categoryjsondata = json.decode(res.body);
    var map = Map<String,dynamic>.from(categoryjsondata);
    var categoryResponse = SubCategoryModel.fromJson(map);

    if(res.statusCode == 200){
      print('category Response: $categoryResponse');
      if(categoryResponse.status == 1){
        //final categoryModel = json.decode(res.body);
        var data = categoryjsondata['data']as List;
        print('category data: $data');

      /*  for(var model in categorieslist){
          categoryNames.add(new SubCategoryData.fromJson(model));
        }*/
    /*    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        print("cat List Size: $categories");
        prefs.setStringList("categorylist", categories);*/
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> ChewieDemo(imageData: images[0],
            categoryData:data)));
      }
    }
  }
```

By using the above code I am trying to send data but I am facing issue like  **type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'SubCategoryData' in type cast"**

got an error and even I am not getting how to send data with an index value.Please let me know.

Below is my **ChewieDemo** class: 
Here I am trying to receive the data from another class.

```
class ChewieDemo extends StatefulWidget {

  final Datum imageData;
  final SubCategoryData categoryData;
  ChewieDemo({this.title = 'Player',Key key,@required this.imageData,@required this.categoryData}): super(key:key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _ChewieDemoState();
  }
}

class _ChewieDemoState extends State<ChewieDemo> {

  TargetPlatform _platform;
  VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController1;
  VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController2;
  ChewieController _chewieController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print('url player :${widget.imageData.dataUrl}');
    print(widget.categoryData);
    // 'https://www.sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/480/big_buck_bunny_480p_20mb.mp4'
    _videoPlayerController1 = VideoPlayerController.network('${widget.imageData.dataUrl}');
    _chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController1,
      aspectRatio: 3 / 2,
      autoPlay: true,
      looping: true,
      // Try playing around with some of these other options:

      // showControls: false,
      // materialProgressColors: ChewieProgressColors(
      //   playedColor: Colors.red,
      //   handleColor: Colors.blue,
      //   backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      //   bufferedColor: Colors.lightGreen,
      // ),
      // placeholder: Container(
      //   color: Colors.grey,
      // ),
      // autoInitialize: true,
    );
  }
```

This is the model class of SubCategoryData.

```
class SubCategoryData {
      int id;
      int parentId;
      String name;
      int contentCount;
      String createdAt;
      int status;

      SubCategoryData({
        this.id,
        this.parentId,
        this.name,
        this.contentCount,
        this.createdAt,
        this.status,
      });

      factory SubCategoryData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => new SubCategoryData(
        id: json["id"],
        parentId: json["parent_id"],
        name: json["name"],
        contentCount: json["content_count"],
        createdAt: json["createdAt"],
        status: json["status"],
      );

      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "parent_id": parentId,
        "name": name,
        "content_count": contentCount,
        "createdAt": createdAt,
        "status": status,
      };

      @override
      String toString() {
        // TODO: implement toString
        return '$id $parentId $name $contentCount';
      }
    }
```

Comment: can you please show the code of ChewieDemo class?

Comment: updated my question.

Comment: you can't use: *categoryData:(categoryData)as SubCategoryData)* because the categoryData is of type list and you can't convert it, what is the SubCategoryData class? show the code of it

Comment: its a model class

Comment: ok so the issue that you can't convert the list to this model class, if you want show the code of the model class so i can help you with filling the data from the list to the model class

Comment: ok.. I updated with my model class.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Add the dependency**

Before starting, you need to add the shared_preferences plugin to the pubspec.yaml file:

```
content_copy
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  shared_preferences: "<newest version>"
```

**2. Save data**

To persist data, use the setter methods provided by the SharedPreferences class. Setter methods are available for various primitive types, such as setInt, setBool, and setString.

Setter methods do two things: First, synchronously update the key-value pair in-memory. Then, persist the data to disk.

```
// obtain shared preferences
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

// set value
prefs.setInt('counter', counter);
```

**3. Read data**

To read data, use the appropriate getter method provided by the SharedPreferences class. For each setter there is a corresponding getter. For example, you can use the getInt, getBool, and getString methods.

```
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

// Try reading data from the counter key. If it does not exist, return 0.
final counter = prefs.getInt('counter') ?? 0;
```

**4. Remove data**

To delete data, use the remove method.

```
content_copy
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

prefs.remove('counter');
```

Comment: i want to store list

Answer (score 0):

you are getting a list of `SubCategoryData` from the `httpcall`. If you need to pass a `List` of your `SubCategoryData` model you need first to fix the following in your `ChewieDemo` class

```
class ChewieDemo extends StatefulWidget {

  final Datum imageData;
  final List<SubCategoryData> categoryData;
  ChewieDemo({this.title = 'Player',Key key,@required this.imageData,@required this.categoryData}): super(key:key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _ChewieDemoState();
  }
}
```

and when you push the following:

```
      var categoryData = categoryjsondata['data'] as List;
      print('category data: $categoryData');

      for(var model in categoryData){
        categoryNames.add(new SubCategoryData.fromJson(model));
      }
      print("cat List Size: $categoryData");
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> ChewieDemo(imageData: null, categoryData: categoryNames));
```

where categoryNames is a `List<SubCategoryData>`

Comment: I tried with this too but still facing the same issue like type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<SubCategoryData>'

Comment: I answered it on your new question